# How do I run KDE widgets in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, kde4

I like xfce in general, but I also like KDE'
S widgets. How do I combine the two on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE's widgets are part of the KDE Plasma Desktop... which is a huge chunk of KDE. [It can be done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26033/can-i-use-kde-plasma-widgets-in-gnome) (you just install `plasma-desktop` and `plasma-scriptengines` and run `plasma-desktop` at start-up) but that is going to override your existing desktop.

I honestly can't say if the end result is something you'll like, but it's the only way I know how to do what you want.